# FP Pattern matching

Tags: scala

I just started to learn FP with Scala so apologize for the question. I found this exercise (Exercise 3.1 https://www.scala-exercises.org/fp_in_scala/functional_data_structures) for pattern matching but I am a bit confuse and having trouble to understand how come the result for X is 3.

```
val x = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) match {
  case Cons(x, Cons(2, Cons(4, _))) => x
  case Nil => 42
  case Cons(x, Cons(y, Cons(3, Cons(4, _)))) => x + y
  case Cons(h, t) => h + sum(t)
  case _ => 101
}
```

Can some please assist here with debugging this scenario step by step ? I believe that this will help me to understand the concept.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all. Now it is clear :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An immutable `List` in Scala is a `Cons`-list. That means that it consists of a series of `Cons`-objects, and is ending with a `Nil`. For example, your list:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

would be this `Cons`-list:

```
Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, Cons(5, Nil)))))
```

When you pattern-match on lists in Scala, you can use this `Cons`-structure. And that is what that example does.

Let me go through each of the patterns to tell you what they do:

1. This one matches if your second element is a 2 and your third element is a 4. If that is the case, the expression returns the first element of the list. The `_` means that you ignore the rest of the list (so it could be 3 elements or more).

   ```
   case Cons(x, Cons(2, Cons(4, _))) => x
   ```
2. This one matches the empty list. If it matches, the expression returns 42.

   ```
   case Nil => 42
   ```
3. This one matches if your third element is 3 and your fourth element is 4. If it matches, the expression returns the sum of the two first elements of the list.

   ```
   case Cons(x, Cons(y, Cons(3, Cons(4, _)))) => x + y
   ```
4. This one matches all lists with at least one element. If it matches, the expression returns the first element plus the sum of the rest of the list (which basically equals the sum of the entire list).

   ```
   case Cons(h, t) => h + sum(t)
   ```
5. This one matches everything else. It is the default case, and returns 101. This should never happen, as all other cases are covered above it.

   ```
   case _ => 101
   ```

As you hopefully can see now, the value of `x` becomes 3 because it matches with the third case. This returns 1 + 2, which equals 3.

Comment: Thank you very much for great explanation

Answer (score 1):

*`List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` matches the pattern `Cons(x, Cons(y, Cons(3, Cons(4, _))))`*

here `x` corresponds to `1`, `y` corresponds to 2, 3 and 4 are in place and ignoring last elem.

so `x + y = 1 + 2`

*Explanation*

list does not match first pattern (`Cons(x, Cons(2, Cons(4, _)))`) because after 2 pattern has 4

list does not match second pattern which is `Nil` because list is not Nil

list matches third pattern

as one pattern is matched ... other cases are not matched. so pattern matching stops matching after 3rd case (which is successful match)

Answer (score 0):

List(1,2,3,4,5) equals to Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Cons(4,Cons(5,Nil)))).

```
val x = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) match {
      case Cons(x, Cons(2, Cons(4, _))) => x //1
      case Nil => 42  //2
      case Cons(x, Cons(y, Cons(3, Cons(4, _)))) => x + y //3
      case Cons(h, t) => h + sum(t) //4 
      case _ => 101 //5
}
```

"_" character means 'Don't Care'

It's important to understand that the first match that supply the pattern would affect the result.

1. cannot be , because its  Cons(2,Cons(**3**,Cons(4,....)))
2. cannot be , because its not Nil , it's Cons
3. this is supplies the pattern since **x** can be equal to 1 , **y** equal to 2 and the rest continue as it is. when he see "_" character he don't care what he see which means it supplied

Answer (score 0):

As you can guess by name `pattern-matching`, the whole expression provided in a `case` is treated as a `Pattern` and is matched to the value being matched.

In this case your matched value is a `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. And lists can also be represented using `infix cons` - `::` (or `postfix cons` - `Cons`).

So this list can be represented as (using `infix cons`),

```
1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: 5 :: Nil
```

or also as (using `postfix cons`),

```
Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Cons(4, Cons(5, Nil))))`
```

And hence you can see that it matches the pattern `Cons(x, Cons(y, Cons(3, Cons(4, _))))`, thus `x` gets matched to value `1` and `y` to value `2` which makes the result `x + y` as `3`.

Answer (score 0):

The list matches the third case, so that’s what you’re looking at. The patterns in the two “lists” are the same. So that third case will yield a result of `x + y` which in this case is 3. To see that, look back at the original parameter `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and observe how it matches the third case; `x = 1`, and `y = 2`; so `x + y = 3`.